# Pathfinding for a destination that is more than 1 tile

Tags: path-finding, grid, tiles

I have a 2d grid, and there are situations where the player selects the 3d model of an exit (like a gate) so they could leave, but in reality, the exit is comprised of multiple tiles in the grid:

[image: Exit with 4 tiles]

In this example, the exit is 4 tiles.

Right now, I'm just thinking of brute-forcing it and doing pathfinding for each exit tile (that means, in the example, 4 times), and just choose the one with the shortest path, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Maybe do it only on the extremities of the tile group (in the example, Exit 1 and Exit 4)?

Maybe edit my A* code such that each tile being searched through has multiple heuristic scores (one for each possible destination tile)? Or maybe the heuristic score I assign is the average of all heuristic scores for each destination tile?

I also want to take into consideration other situations in the future where the exit tiles are not necessarily adjacent to each other, even if collectively they are considered one single exit, like this:

[image: Exit with 4 tiles]

So it should figure out that Exit 5 is the shortest path.

Comment: Ok, this was marked duplicate. I kept searching with the keyword "destination" (which did not give anything useful) but turns out the existing question used the word "goal". I wish stack exchange understood synonyms, I wouldn't have needed to bother making this question.

Comment: Good note. I've added the "destination" keyword to my answer to improve its searchability in future. This question itself will also serve as a waypoint that folks searching similar terms can find, pointing them on toward the existing answer. One note: a heuristic for A* must be admissible - it can never over-estimate the distance. So averaging is risky. If you want to digest multiple estimates down to a single heuristic, you should take the minimum in order to guarantee the combination is as admissible as your inputs.

Comment: Noted, thanks! I read your answer as well on the other question and will be trying that out.